# Initiate click event for every instance of an element

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, element, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to initiate a click event for multiple instances of an element with a javascript bookmarklet. My goal is to be able to click on the bookmarklet and have it delete specific elements, such as whenever a button says remove. Could you help me with this please, I have tried vark.com and other sources to find this answer.

My goal is to achieve this in Google Chrome, can you help me?

Updated:  Here is a more detailed explanation

```
<a class="page_link" title="Visit Page" href="http://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/versionhistory/" target="_blank">Version History - Macro Recorder, Macro Program, Mouse...</a>
```

This can be found by having PageMonitor installed in Chrome, clicking options and inspect element where it shows the name of the site you are monitoring.

Example:

Version History - Macro Recorder, Macro Program, Mouse...<--- This is the link

advanced   rename   remove    Last Check: 11 seconds ago.<--- These are the options

Perhaps nodes was the wrong term, let me see.

remove

Where it says remove, I would like to initiate a click event that will press the Remove button every time it occurs [Screenshot of PageMonitor options window](http://screensnapr.com/v/uezjiX.png)

Comment: do you want the bookmarklet to actually delete the nodes, or make them deletable, say by clicking?  In either case, how do you identify which nodes are to be deleted?

Comment: Well, they are already deletable through the inspect element window, but I would like to delete them by doing the following:

>Having a window appear that says do you want to delete all instances of this node?

Upon clicking that, the nodes will be deleted, basically automating the process of going into inspect element, searching for the instances and hitting delete each time.  I know this is possible, but I am not a Javascript/Jquery expert.

The second part of your question is how to identify, well I will identify them by including a dropdown in the window allowing me to choose the id/class

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "instances" of a node.  In the DOM there are different types of nodes, ex: tags, text nodes, XML comment nodes, etc.  And then within element nodes, there are different kinds, ex: div, p, span, etc.  And then those can have different content, css classes, ids, etc.  So the question remains - *which nodes* do you want to get rid of?

Comment: Perhaps nodes was the wrong term, let me see.

Comment: So it sounds like you're hoping to develop a bookmarklet to automaticaly click the "remove" link wherever it appears on the page, thereby removing everything that PageMonitor is currently watching.  Is this correct?

Comment: Correct, everything except the developing part, since I am not a developer.  I was wondering if there is a way to do it.  I just found it I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347110/a-bookmarklet-that-adds-an-onclick-event-to-every-element-on-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for explaining what you want to do.  Unfortunately, I don't think this is going to be possible.  Playing with PageMonitor, it doesn't appear to be possible to execute javascript in the address bar (necessary to make a bookmarklet) and have it affect the extension page.

The code to implement the feature you want is very easy though, and they could probably just add it to the extension if you asked them to.  Here's the code:

```
$('.stop_monitoring:not(:first)').click()
```

Sadly, as I said, I don't think you can bookmarkletify this due to zone restrictions.  Unsafe browser JS is run in a different zone from trusted extension JS.  Hope this helps. :/

Comment: It works like a charm.  Thanks for giving me a head start jimbojw.